# Different serach results for Calendarview and Events

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I was trying following two queries and only 1st query give correct events results according the given date range.
Is there any reason for giving all events when i use **me/events** in 2nd request ?

1st

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview?startdatetime=2020-07-02T10:20:52.032Z&enddatetime=2020-07-09T10:20:52.032Z
```

2nd

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?startdatetime=2020-07-02T10:20:52.032Z&enddatetime=2020-07-09T10:20:52.032Z
```

Response of 2nd query
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `startDateTime` and `endDateTime` query parameters aren't used by the `/me/events` endpoint. Those are specific to `/me/calendarview`.

Calendar view requires a "time window", because it expands recurring events and returns an entry for each occurrence that happens between those times. If it wasn't bounded, this could result in infinite occurrences, since you can create recurring events with no end date :).

The `/me/events` endpoint doesn't expand recurring events, so it just returns the series masters and single-occurrences on the calendar.